# How to use Ambassador api gateway as a PostgreSQL-aware proxy?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, envoyproxy

I am using Ambassador to manage my Kubernetes services.  My Kubernetes services consist of a few web servers and a few postgres.  I followed the instructions [here](https://www.getambassador.io/user-guide/getting-started/)to establish routes to my web servers.  Here is an example:

```
  annotations:
    getambassador.io/config: |
      ---
      apiVersion: ambassador/v1
      kind:  Mapping
      name:  somewebservice
      prefix: /somewebservice
      service: somewebservice:80
```

This works perfectly for my webserver.  I can do `curl localhost/somewebservice` and I get the expected response.

I have set up the same annotation in my postgres container, but I cannot do a psql.

```
  annotations:
    getambassador.io/config: |
      ---
      apiVersion: ambassador/v1
      kind:  Mapping
      name:  atlas
      prefix: /somepostgres
      service: somepostgres:5432
```

I see the following:

```
$ psql -h 'localhost/somepostgres' -p 5432
psql: could not translate host name "localhost/somepostgres" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

My goal is to have Ambassador accept both HTTP/HTTPS & postgres requests.
  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres is a TCP service (Layer 4) and not an HTTP(s) service (Layer 7). [It doesn't look like Ambassador supports TCP only services](https://www.getambassador.io/reference/mappings#services), even though the [Envoy proxy supports it](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/tcp_proxy). So you'll have to do with a regular Kubernetes TCP service, something like this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: postgres
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5432
```